# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type. / Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I just started writing with Flutter.I am constantly getting this error. What should i do? Here is my code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
body: FutureBuilder<WeatherInfo>(
future: futureWeather,
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (snapshot.hasData) {
} else if  (snapshot.hasError) {
return Center(
child: Text("${snapshot.error}"),
);
```

Comment: please give your full source code

Comment: Which Error are you getting?

Comment: Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: @MdOmorFaruqe I updated the question, I wrote all the code.

Comment: @croxx5f As I wrote in my thread;
"The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder<WeatherInfo>(
            future: futureWeather,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text("${snapshot.error}"),
                );
              }
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }));
  }
```

Inside the FutureBuilder you covered the case in which you have the data or you have an error, but not when you are expecting for the future to complete(And don't have neither the data or an error).

I just added a Circular progress indicator to be shown while no data or no error are returned from the Future, that should prevent the FutureBuilder from returning null. And when the snapshot state changes the data or error would be shown.

Comment: It stuck at loading what should I do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70582622/the-body-might-complete-normally-causing-null-to-be-returned-but-the-return

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try and wrap the future builder in a container

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Please provide code sample for your answer