# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type error with StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I was trying to put a GridView widget inside of a StreamBuilder, but I get this error.

```
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.
```

I saw a lot of post related to this but I couldn't use the answers. They are mostly unrelated.

The thing is, when I add `return Container();` or `return const CircularProgressIndicator();` to end of the my StreamBuilder function, the code is works but It doesn't show anything. I think it some how passes the `return GridView.builder` statement.

Also I check the stream and there is data inside of it. So it doesn't return null or something like that.

Here is my code, this is the version **without** `return Container();` or `return const CircularProgressIndicator();`:

```
Widget _ContentGridView() {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _stuffStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('posts') //seçilen döküman
      .orderBy('dateTime',
          descending: true) //veriler yeniden eskiye şeklinde listeleniyor
      .snapshots();
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _stuffStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Try agin later');
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            print(data['title']);
            return GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                      child: GridTile(
                        child: Center(
                          child: GridContent(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ));
          }).toList();
        } else {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      });
}
```

The `GridContent()`, declared as a Widget in the code.

```
Widget GridContent() {
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  String productName;
  return ListView(children: [
    Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 25),
......
...
..
rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error might be caused by the lack of a `return` in your `StreamBuilder` function body.

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
  return Text('Try agin later');
}
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
}
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  // add a return to this block below
  return ListView(children: // or a Column(children: 
    snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
      ... 
    }).toList()
  );
} else {
  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
}
```

Comment: Hi, this time I got a `The return type 'List<Column>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.` error which contains [some code block.](https://i.imgur.com/3GQPEPR.png)

Comment: Oh Right.... you need to return a single widget.... not a List... one sec, lemme update my answer

Comment: Hi again, I tried it with Listview  and Container but I got `The argument type 'Iterable<ListView>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'.` error. So I added a `<Widget>` statement near to the map but this time I got `The argument type 'Iterable<Widget>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'.` error this time. There is a `toList();` statement in the end of the code. is that one shouldn't be to the job?